# Access Database Remote Connection

Tags: ms-access, authentication, odbc, database-connection, remote-access

There are 2 systems Configured to connect with Remotely set up Server.

1. Local System A
2. Local System B

   when i try to run an Access Database in Local System A , its perfectly good.
   but when i try to run the same Access Database in Local System B , it fails with ODBC Connection error.

When My Colleague logins to the Local System B and try to Run that particular Access Database it Runs Perfectly good.

Why is the issue - "ODBC Conection Error" Only appears for me?

The System settings are perfectly alright while my Login Profile is also good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it test successfully in the ODBC data source administrator when you are logged in?  If so then check your connection property on your tables.  Are they using trusted connection?  If so, check your permissions in your server for your login.  If not, check they match the credentials in the ODBC data source.

It sounds like a permission issue somewhere since your colleague can run it just fine.  If all else fails sometimes selecting Named Pipes under client configuration or setting the IP address (instead of the server name) works.

Comment: Connection Property in table is good ,here the Database itself has issue with the Connection to Remote Server